# diagbox and multirow: adjust the diagonal

Tags: tables, multirow, diagbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow,pict2e}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox} %table split headers
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{makecell,caption}


\newcommand{\ext}[0]{{\texttt{ext}}}
\newcommand{\nv}[0]{{\texttt{nv}}}
\newcommand{\nvlca}[0]{{\texttt{nv.lca}}}
\newcommand{\nvsuc}[0]{{\texttt{nv.succ}}}
\newcommand{\wthpd}[0]{{\texttt{wt.hpd}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\ra{1.5}
%\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|rrr|rrrrr@{}}
\toprule
    \multirow{3}{*}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=3\line]%
    {\\ \\Dataset}{Method\\ \\}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{plain} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{advanced}\\
                                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{\nv} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvlca} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ext} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvsuc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\wthpd} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ext}\\
                                                    & {}                  & {}                      & {}                   & {}                       & 
                                                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}}\\
    \midrule
    {\texttt{eu.mst.osm}} & {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
    {\texttt{eu.emst.dem}}& {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I use `diagbox` in conjunction with `multirow`, and cannot get the diagonal line to actually touch the north-west and south-east corners of the box.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use an `arraystretch` of `1.5` for your table, you will have to change the height of the `diagbox` from `3\line` to `4.5\line`. However, you will notice the small gap between the diagonal horizontal line as well as between the vertical and the horizontal lines. This is due to the usage of the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package that are incompatible with vertical lines.

In the second example, I have therefore replaced the lines from `booktabs` by `\hlines` to the gaps disappear. I have also removed the `\resizebox` as this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout your document.

Personally, I would redesign your table, as shown in the third example, wihout vertical and diagonal lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow,pict2e}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox} %table split headers
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{makecell,caption}


\newcommand{\ext}[0]{{\texttt{ext}}}
\newcommand{\nv}[0]{{\texttt{nv}}}
\newcommand{\nvlca}[0]{{\texttt{nv.lca}}}
\newcommand{\nvsuc}[0]{{\texttt{nv.succ}}}
\newcommand{\wthpd}[0]{{\texttt{wt.hpd}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\ra{1.5}
%\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|rrr|rrrrr@{}}
\toprule
    \multirow{3}{*}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=4.5\line]%
    {\\ \\Dataset}{Method\\ \\}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{plain} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{advanced}\\
                                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{\nv} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvlca} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ext} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvsuc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\wthpd} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ext}\\
                                                    & {}                  & {}                      & {}                   & {}                       & 
                                                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}}\\
    \midrule
    {\texttt{eu.mst.osm}} & {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
    {\texttt{eu.emst.dem}}& {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\ra{1.5}
%\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|rrr|rrrrr@{}}
\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\diagbox[trim=l,height=4.5\line]%
    {\\ \\Dataset}{Method\\ \\}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{plain} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{advanced}\\
                                                    & \multirow{2}{*}{\nv} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvlca} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ext} & \multirow{2}{*}{\nvsuc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\wthpd} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ext}\\
                                                    & {}                  & {}                      & {}                   & {}                       & 
                                                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{p}}\\
    \hline
    {\texttt{eu.mst.osm}} & {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
    {\texttt{eu.emst.dem}}& {x} & {y} & {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table*}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccccc@{}}
\toprule
 Dataset & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Methods} \\ \cmidrule{2-9}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{plain} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{advanced}\\ \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule{5-9}
                                                    & \nv & \nvlca & \ext & \nvsuc & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\wthpd} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ext}\\ \cmidrule(r){6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
                                                    & {}                  & {}                      & {}                   & {}                       & 
                                                    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \textit{p} & \textit{c} & \textit{p}\\
    \midrule
    \texttt{eu.mst.osm} & x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
    \texttt{eu.emst.dem}& x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've adopted your redesign.

Answer (score 1):

*A variant*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx, array, multirow, pict2e}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{diagbox} %table split headers
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{makecell,caption}

\newcommand{\ext}[0]{{\texttt{ext}}}
\newcommand{\nv}[0]{{\texttt{nv}}}
\newcommand{\nvlca}[0]{{\texttt{nv.lca}}}
\newcommand{\nvsuc}[0]{{\texttt{nv.succ}}}
\newcommand{\wthpd}[0]{{\texttt{wt.hpd}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{8}{c}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Met\rlap{hods:}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{plain} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{advanced}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-9}
\makecell{\multirow{2.3}{*}{Dataset}} & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\nv} & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\nvlca} & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\ext} & \multirow{2.3}{*}{\nvsuc} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\wthpd} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ext}\\
\cmidrule(r){6-7} \cmidrule{8-9}
& & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{c}} & \textit{p} & \textit{c} & \textit{p}\\
\midrule
\texttt{eu.mst.osm} & x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
\texttt{eu.emst.dem}& x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can construct such table with `nicematrix`.

However, as said in other answers, I would recommend a design in the spirit of `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily}l|rrr|rrrrr@{}}
\toprule
\Block{3-1}
  {
    \diagbox
      {\rule[-2mm]{0pt}{2mm}Dataset}
      {\rule{0pt}{4mm}Method }
  } 
& \Block{1-3}{plain} &&& \Block{1-5}{advanced} \\
\RowStyle{\ttfamily}
& \Block{2-1}{nv} & \Block{2-1}{nv.lca} & \Block{2-1}{ext} & \Block{2-1}{nv.succ} & \Block{1-2}{wt.hpd} && \Block{1-2}{ext} \\
\RowStyle{\itshape} & & & & & c & p & c & p\\
\midrule
eu.mst.osm & x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
eu.emst.dem & x & y & a & b & c & d & e & f\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]